# Addition of 2 numbers from keyboard using spartan 3 (vhdl)

Tags: vhdl

My task is to take 2 inputs from keyboard which is numbers from 0 to 9 and to add them. Problem is in 
STORING these numbers.i want to save first press(input no.) into "a" and second press(input no.) into
"b" but by using following code first press stores in both a and b. 2nd press is of no use. here
scan_code = scancode of the pressed button (output of keyboard interfacing code)
a  = number in binary (for example if first time i press "1" then the code check the scancode and assign the binary value of "1" to a).
Any one who can help?

```
process (clk, scan_code, cin)
  variable scancode1 : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := "00000000";
  variable cin2      : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin
  if(clk'event and clk = '1') then

    scancode1 := scan_code;
    a         <= "0000";
    b         <="0000";
    if (scancode1 = "00010110") then
      a <= "0001";
    elsif (scancode1 = "00011110") then
      a <="0010";
    elsif (scancode1 = "00100110") then
      a <="0011";
    elsif (scancode1 = "00100101") then
      a <="0100";
    elsif (scancode1 = "00101110") then
      a <="0101";
    elsif(scancode1 = "00110110") then
      a <="0110";
    elsif (scancode1 = "00111101") then
      a <="0111";
    elsif (scancode1 = "00111110") then
      a <="1000";
    elsif (scancode1 = "01000110") then
      a <="1001";
    elsif (scancode1 = "01000101") then
      a <="0000";
    end if;

    if (scancode1 = "01010101") then    --scancode for + sign
      a <=a;
    end if;

    if (scancode1 = "00010110") then
      b <="0001";
    elsif (scancode1 = "00011110") then
      b <="0010";
    elsif (scancode1 = "00100110") then
      b <="0011";
    elsif (scancode1 = "00100101") then
      b <="0100";
    elsif (scancode1 = "00101110") then
      b <="0101";
    elsif(scancode1 = "00110110") then
      b <="0110";
    elsif (scancode1 = "00111101") then
      b <="0111";
    elsif (scancode1 = "00111110") then
      b <="1000";
    elsif (scancode1 = "01000110") then
      b <="1001";
    elsif (scancode1 = "01000101") then
      b <="0000";
    end if;

    sum(0)  <= a(0) xor b(0) xor cin;
    cin2(0) := (a(0) and b(0)) or (cin and (a(0) xor b(0)));

    sum(1)  <= a(1) xor b(1) xor cin2(0);
    cin2(1) := (a(1) and b(1)) or (cin2(0) and (a(1) xor b(1)));

    sum(2)  <= a(2) xor b(2) xor cin2(1);
    cin2(2) := (a(2) and b(2)) or (cin2(1) and (a(2) xor b(2)));

    sum(3) <= a(3) xor b(3) xor cin2(2);
    cout   <= (a(3) and b(3)) or (cin2(2) and (a(3) xor b(3)));

  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: One of your problems is probably that `a` and `b` only get their new values the next time the process is called. Signals are only updated after the process has run completely. While the process is running they retain the value they had when it was called. You should probably store `a` and `b` in temporary variables in the beginning, and assign their new values on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

"a" and "b" are updating at the same time as you wrote it like that (same "scancodes" are checked for "a" and "b" on the same clockedge). think about using an event trigger like in the following example:

```
...
if reset='1' then
   a<=(others => '0');
   b<=(others => '0');
   event_last<='0';
   event_nr<=0;

elsif rising_edge(clk) then 
   event_last<=event;

   -- trigger on "rising edge" of event
   if event='1' and event_last='0' then

        case event_nr is
        -- first event is "a"
        when 0 =>
            event_nr<=1;

            if (scancode1 = "00010110") then
                 a <= "0001";
            ...

        -- second event is "b"
        when others => 
            event_nr<=0;

            if (scancode1 = "00010110") then
                b <= "0001";
            ...
        end case;

   ...
   ...
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is event_nr and event.is it a signal of our choice or a set/reset button or clock. i didn't get this point.

Comment: "event" means the event of key-press. As I don't know your complete code and HW setup I can only guess... you might look out for scancode1 to change (e.g.  if scancode1/=scancode1_last then event<='1'; scancode1_last<=scancode1;else event<='0'; scancode1_last<=scancode1; end if;)